# Return flattened array from each element in a nested array mongo with aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection setup with documents that look like :

```
     {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c786d9486c1140b1452d777"),
        "code" : "TEST-123",
        "owner" : "John",
        "cars" : [ 
            {
                "carPlate" : "QPZ-756",
                "carColor" : "blue"
            }, 
            {
                "carPlate" : "REF-473",
                "carColor" : "red"
            }
        ],
     }
```

I'm looking for an mongo aggregate query that grabs each carPlate and outputs the following for every document in the collection

```
        {
           "carPlate" : "QPZ-756",
           "owner" : "John",
           "code" : "TEST-123",
        },
        {
           "carPlate" : "REF-473",
           "owner" : "John",
           "code" : "TEST-123",
        },
```

I had a look at the $map operator, would this be a good place to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to flatten the array followed  by [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) to combine keys along with [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to promote the merge documents to the top.

Something like

```
db.colname.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$cars"},
    {$replaceRoot:{newRoot:{$mergeObjects:[{owner:"$owner"}, "$cars"]}}}
])
```